# How to update gnome-shell?

Tags: gnome

I'm on Ubuntu-gnome 15.04 Vivid which includs gnome-shell 3.14 
Is there anyway to update shell to 3.16 or 3.18 ?

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu 15.10, (recently released), has gnome-shell 3.16.

```
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

I was able to do an upgrade without much incident, (with the exception of KDE applications acting strange).

Hope that helps!